# Удаление слова из строки

Tags: java

Есть строка: "Сегодня&#171 был хороший день". Так у меня парсит Json. Как убрать это слово из строки? &#171

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот моя реализация.

```
String regex = "[^&#171]";
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(postModel.title);

while (matcher.find()) {
    stringBuilder.append(matcher.group(0));
}
postModel.title = stringBuilder.toString();
//postModel - класс, у которого есть поле title, оно в свою очередь принимает json строку, далее я ее обрабатываю
```

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно удалить конкретную подстроку из строки, то может помочь `replaceAll()`.

```
String str = "javaTest";
System.out.println(str);
String newStr = str.replaceAll("Test", "");
System.out.println(newStr);
```

Вывод:

```
javaTest
java
```

Comment: У вас здесь появляется пробел, мне это не надо

Comment: Скорее всего вы написали " ", то есть с заменой на пробел, а нужно просто ""

Answer (score 0):

вот с# наверное можно и так

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example{
    public static void Main(){
    string pattern = @"[^#171]";
    string input = @" ""Сегодня&#171 был хороший день""";
    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

      foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
          {
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
          }
    }
}
```

но я думаю, что на самом деле тебе нужно загуглить ***DeEntitize***
и написать в нужном место что-то вроде
`string deEntitized = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(encoded);`
UPDATE: проглядел тег java но суть кажется одна и таже 
*NotaBene: я ни в шарпе ни в яве не шарю, просто загуглил*

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "[^#171]";
final String string = "\"Сегодня&#171 был хороший день\"";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Извеняюсь, но вопрос вообще то имет метку Java. Вы уверены, что он поможет ТС?

Comment: думаю, что автору ответ не нужен - уже выгуглил все ;)

Comment: Интересно, а отчего в текст попала открывающая левая кавычка #xAB и где парная ей #xBB (#187)?